# Facebook Graph API Intersecting Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am messing with the Graph API for a personal project and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to find the number of intersecting likes between two pages.  I have no problem getting the number of likes for individual pages using the API, but can't find any documentation about overlap/intersect.  If one manually searches, "People who like Kobe Bryant and Dwayne Wade" the search spits out results for users who like both pages with, "more than 1,000 users" above the filters on the right and this URL: https://www.facebook.com/search/69025400418/likers/110401235654238/likers/intersect .  Is there a way to use the Graph API to get the actual number of users who like both pages?

Comment: No. Via API you will neither get individual users for any page, nor does such an intersection method exist.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate.  Thanks.